# in emacs-lisp, how do I correctly use replace-regexp-in-string?

Tags: regex, emacs, lisp

Given a string, I want to replace all links within it with the link's description.  For example, given

```
this is a [[http://link][description]]
```

I would like to return

```
this is a description
```

I used re-builder to construct this regexp for a link:

```
\\[\\[[^\\[]+\\]\\[[^\\[]+\\]\\]
```

This is my function:

```
(defun flatten-string-with-links (string)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\[\\[[^\\[]+\\]\\[[^\\[]+\\]\\]"
                (lambda(s) (nth 2 (split-string s "[\]\[]+"))) string))
```

Instead of replacing the entire regexp sequence, it only replaces the trailing "]]".  This is what it produces:

```
this is a [[http://link][descriptiondescription
```

I don't understand what's going wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I've improved the regex for the link.  It's irrelevant to the question but if someone's gonna copy it they may as well get the better version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that `split-string` is clobbering the match data, which
`replace-regexp-in-string` is relying on being unchanged, since it is going to
go use that match data to decide which sections of the string to cut out. This
is arguably a doc bug in that `replace-regexp-in-string` does not mention that
your replacement function must preserve the match data.

You can work around by using `save-match-data`, which is a macro provided for
exactly this purpose:

```
(defun flatten-string-with-links (string)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\[\\[[a-zA-Z:%@/\.]+\\]\\[[a-zA-Z:%@/\.]+\\]\\]"
                (lambda (s) (save-match-data
                         (nth 2 (split-string s "[\]\[]+")))) string))
```